# Wordpress wont load completely acessing remotely on Wamp

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wamp

I have installed **WAMP Developer Pro** on my computer running Windows 7 this is a testing website, it was setup locally and now the next step is testing it on the LAN, the page can be accessed, it loads the text but no image/theme/styling.

The Apache is running on port 80 fowarded and open.

i **dont** have the wordpress adress in settings to localhost or any of the like.

i need any advice if the css or the templates call from localhost and if changing it its the solution im looking for curently reading every single one at the moment.

Most of the answers ive read so far are: question, vague answer, op says solved and no explanation is made whatsoever, been searching here and there for 3 days now but none of it has helped me so far if anyone got even a link regarding this problem with a walktrough-like solution would be appreciated.

Comment: google wamp virtual hosts, its not easy to set up but it should be well represented online. But an easy fix is to manually include your files using relative paths in the footer, you can change for production code.

Answer (score 0):

> it loads the text but no image/theme/styling

That is a sure sign of the link URLs for the images and CSS being of the form: `http://localhost/`, or `127.0.0.1`, or maybe a domain-name that is not accessable from outside the local system (for multiple reasons).

> i dont have the wordpress adress in settings to localhost or any of the like.

Are you sure?

If you click in your Browser to display the source-code of the page (the HTML code), you'll see the address the links are using.

For this to work, it would have to be (**and matching the website's domain name**): the LAN IP address, the LAN host-name, or a resolvable domain-name.

There is a howto on WampDeveloper's site that deals with this specific problem (text but no images nor style)...

[Website Only Shows Text Content With All Graphics Missing](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/website-only-shows-text-content-with-all-graphics-missing)

This one might also help: "Accessing Websites on a Local Network (LAN) Web Server"

Edit: It could also be an issue with the theme or its path. And/or .htaccess rewrite rules - mucking things up.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing a plugin called **[Relative URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/)** Which changes all post link/images/pages/etc. instances to relative functions so they can be viewed from outside the host machine, no coding needed though id dig later on how its does it.Seems like the problem was that the theme itself either could not be modified or was hidden enough to make those changes.

The page in general settings was right, it was the theme/plugins hard coded to localhost.

Thanks to all for the suggestions and resources.